# Can't connect to MongoDB through heroku but works on localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, backend

Trying to push my simple notes app to heroku but when launched on heroku mongoDB gives me this error

```
Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster.
```

My backend works perfectly fine while my app is running locally and I have whitelisted all IPs in mongoDB and added MONGODB_URI as a local var in heroku so I'm unsure what is wrong at this point.

Here is my connection.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI

console.log('Connecting to..', url)

mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true })
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error connecting to MongoDB: `, error.message)
    })
```

Comment: Do you see the URL here `console.log('Connecting to..', url)` on Heroku logs?

Comment: @fortunee Yes I see my url in my heroku logs

Comment: Are you using any vpn proxy?

Comment: @fortunee Nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by deleting my whitelist in mongoDB Atlas and then adding it back, my server connected on heroku after that.